# подскажите библиотеку bootstrap, чтоб нормально работала

Tags: html, bootstrap

Я задавал подобный вопрос, но исправляя одну проблему - получаю другую проблему...Подскажите рабочую версию библиотеки бутстрап? чтоб срабатывал dropdown, carusel, img-responsive и желательно одновременно...Вот код с пордключением к Bootstrap CDN:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>yeti</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords">
    <meta name="description" content="description">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid yeti-body">
<div class="container ">   
   <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.sunhome.ru/UsersGallery/Cards/prazdnik_den_zemli_kartinka.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.sunhome.ru/UsersGallery/Cards/prazdnik_den_zemli_kartinka.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.sunhome.ru/UsersGallery/Cards/prazdnik_den_zemli_kartinka.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
 </button>
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Консоль браузера выдает:

```
bootstrap.min.js:formatted:7 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
at bootstrap.min.js:formatted:7
(anonymous) @   bootstrap.min.js:formatted:7
```

Comment: Вот версия которой сам пользуюсь. + CDN https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто подключите `jQuery` до `bootstrap.min.js`
А вообще, я делаю как-то так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Page </title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 ...Some Code....
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Вы меня спасли от того, чтоб НЕ сойти с ума)спасибо Вам. Обидно что такая вот мелочь так портит жизнь...

Comment: @Александр всегда пожалуйста. В целом, лучше периодически заходить на http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ и проверять, какая версия сейчас на их сайте, я так делаю каждый раз, когда начинаю новый проект. Законченный переводить не всегда рискую( вдруг чего-то поломается), а вот новую вёрстку делаю с актуальным бутстрапом)

Comment: Klimenkomud подскажите, пожалуйста, по этому вопросу, если можете. Заранее спасибо    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688428/%d0%b2-phpstorm-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8-bootstrap-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5