# в PHPStorm исчезает подсказка классов библиотеки bootstrap при подключии собственного css-файла

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, phpstorm

В общем....суть проблемы такова...в PHPStorm исчезает подсказка классов библиотеки bootstrap (класс container, например), когда я подключаю библиотеку fa (фавиконы) и свой CSS-файл (строка 1 и строка 2). Причем, подсказка классов bootstrap начинает работать, когда я удаляю ОБЕ строки (строки 1,2).
Вот head кода:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <link href="bootstrap/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> <!-- строка 1 -->
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><!-- строка 2-->
</head>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не могу вам помочь с этим, попробую спросить у коллеги, возможно он подскажет

Comment: @Klimenkomud ,спасибо огромное

Comment: очень странно... 2 первых `<link>` тега в комплишене не участвуют никак - online ресурсы, доступные по CDN ссылкам, не индексируются, для комплишена необходимо иметь все css файлы на диске, в директории проекта. Так что каким образом вообще может работать комплишен для bootstrap - непонятно. возможно, у вас все-таки есть bootstrap.css файл в проекте? Тогда нужно добавить на него ссылку, и комплишен появится

Comment: @lena, спасибо Вам, а bootstrap.css в проекте НЕ будет ли конфликтовать с подключенной библиотекой по CDN ссылкам?

Comment: Вы можете использовать ссылку на локальный bootstrap.css в процессе разработки, и закомментировать ее в production (заменить на CDN reference). К сожалению, в данный момент это единственный workaround:(

Comment: @lena , lena, спасибо большое)только прикол в том, что в локальном бутстрапе поче-то не срабатывают некоторые классы...(carousel, dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStorm дает подсказку классов, которые находятся в проекте. lena дала подсказку, что бы я подключил локально bootstrap-библиотеку. Решение данной проблемы у меня обстояло следующим образом:
Я подключил библиотеку bootstrap при помощи CDN-ссылок и поместил в проект папку с библиотекой bootstrap (но НЕ подключал ее). В итоге проект работает на библиотеке при помощи CDN-ссылок, а подсказку PHPStorm берет из помещенной в проект папки с библиотекой bootstrap.
П.С.: после завершения проекта папку с библиотекой bootstrap нужно будет удалить